# Searching for a software for creating UML diagrams

Tags: windows, software-development, programming, mind-mapping

I very like UML diagrams, and recently I used [Codeuml](http://codeuml.com/) and [PlantText UML Editor](http://planttext.com) for easy creating diagrams from text, using PlantUML syntax.

I very like the result, except that I prefer a direct edit the diagram. I very like freemind/freeplane software. (Lot of shortcuts, and everything can be made with keyboard), the only problem is that those map mind tools, not have all the options that plantuml have (sceniacrio cases, messages between components, ...)

I am attaching 2 simple diagrams for example I want to create.
I will appreciate any answer, but I prefer something that it is portable, and window support.

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend **StarUML**.

> **StarUML** is an open source project to develop fast, flexible, extensible, featureful, and freely-available UML/MDA platform running on Win32 platform. The goal of the StarUML project is to build a software modeling tool and also a platform that is a compelling replacement of commercial UML tools such as Rational Rose, Together and so on. (from old projects of [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/v1), this project has been discontinued).

The good news is StarUML starts the new project (since long time no updates).

[**StarUML 2**](http://staruml.io/) is new project from *MKLab* as the next version of **StarUML v1**. The new version is compatible with **UML 2.x** standard and supports totally 11 kinds of UML diagrams (use case diagram, activity diagram, class diagram, sequence diagram and more). StarUML is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X now.

Taken from [StarUML docs](http://staruml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling-with-uml/organizing-project.html):

You can start a modeling project by selecting a template. To start a project with a template, **select File | New From Template | TemplateName**. StarUML supports 4 default templates:

- UMLMinimal - A single model with UML Standard Profile.
- UMLConventional - Use Case Model, Analysis Model, Design Model,
- Implementation Model, and Deployment Model with UML Standard Profile.
- 4+1 View Model - [Pilippe Kruchten’s 4+1 Architectural View Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model).
- Rational: Approach of Rational Rose Tool.

StarUML 2 is **free** to **download**, **no time limit for evaluation**, a **license should be purchased** for continued use. I usually draw my UML diagram with this tool. For any information, let's take a look the [main site](http://staruml.io/)!

Example use case diagram.

[image: Use case diagram in StarUML 2]

Comment: You're welcome. I hope this application satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) is portable and has Windows support. It's free.
Also yEd has browser version: [yEd Live](https://www.yworks.com/yed-live/).

It is similar to Freeplane, it allows you to draw diagrams with the mouse, but also contains a set of figures for UML to create Activity, Use Case and Class diagrams. I use it mostly to draw Сlass diagrams.

Screenshot of current version:
[image: yEd diagram editor for UML]

> To install the **portable version**, go to [official site](https://www.yworks.com/downloads#yEd), click on the `+` icon below the caption `Show all yEd downloads`, and download the zip archive that is opposite the caption:
> `Java - Zipped yEd Jar file for 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. Requires an installed Java 8 (or later) runtime environment.`
> Unpack this archive and run yEd with the command: `java -jar yed.jar`

Helpful links:
[yEd Manual for UML - Webpage](https://yed.yworks.com/support/manual/uml.html)
[yEd Live: UML Diagram Editor (browser version) - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJqhEDYIIhE)